# getting connection refused while connection android app to jboss server

Tags: java, android, web-services, sockets, jboss

I'm trying to test my **Android Application** that connects to a `jboss` server via `Web Service`.
The program works just fine when I use 127.0.0.1 or my internal IP(with internet acces). But whenever I switch to my network with no internet access(like adhoc), it throws a
 `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect error.`

but I can access to the server by typing the **IP address:port** in the browser.

If I'm pinging to the server IP address the ping will succeed.

I turned off the firwall but always the  same result.

Any ideas on what to do about this? Thanks

Comment: Throwing it out there,,, check whether other ipaddresses are accepted by JBoss.. Is this only from Android? or also from non-Android

Comment: ip adress accepted : 192.168.1.9 : with internet acces 
ip adress throwing exception 192.168.1.100 : without internet acces

Comment: There can be so many problems :(... What OS are you running? Maybe you need a port pass?

Comment: windows 7 with jboss-4.2.3.GA

Comment: `But whenever I switch to my network with no internet access(like adhoc), it throws a java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect error.` but you need internet! huh? Can't you just add internet to Android? Then you'll probably need an external ipaddress...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be a JBoss parameter for ipaddresses (that's by default turned off).

But you'll need internet to use the service if you want to use an Android device to call it. Or need to make sure the Android device gets a local ip... Then call through 192.xxx not 127.0.0.1...

Best would be to check the router/firewall so that the external ip:port is ported to your dev computer... Then let Android (using internet) call the external ipaddress...

Answer (score 0):

this is the submit code that send the login and password to the server

```
try {
    json.put("utCode", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_login)).getText());
    json.put("utPassword", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pass)).getText());
    new PostLogin().execute(Settings.getServerAddress(getBaseContext()) + "/auth/login", json);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}


private class PostLogin extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String url = (String) params[0];
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) params[1];

        // Dummy code
        InputStream is = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;  
        try {
            response = RestEasy.doPost(url, json);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 500) {
                return "500";
            } else if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 404) {
                return "404";
            }

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {

                is = entity.getContent();

                String result = "";
                result = RestEasy.convertStreamToString(is);
                return result;
            } else {
                return "null";
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the code run with no problems when I use a network with internet access but if i use a network without internet access  it throws a

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect error.
```